# How can i get the selected column in C#, SQL

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I have the following Code/SQL statement in my C# project but the select statement doesnt show the values what are in the column it only shows the column name why is this ?

my code

```
 string Table = ListBox2.Text;
string column= listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem);

            foreach (object Tables in ListBox2.SelectedItems)
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter SQLStatement = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT '"+column+"' FROM " + table, ConnectionString))
                {
                    DataTable dt= new DataTable();
                    SQLStatement.Fill(dt);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    dataGridView1.Refresh();

                }
            }
```

Comment: Not related: `dataGridView1.Refresh();` is redundant. `dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;` will update datagridview with new values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `SELECT '"+column+"' FROM table_name`,generated query will be something like this: `SELECT "column" FROM table_name`.

Please try this:

```
string sqlCommandStatement = string.Format("SELECT {0} FROM {1}", column,table);

using (SqlDataAdapter SQLStatement = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommandStatement, ConnectionString))
            {
                DataTable dt= new DataTable();
                SQLStatement.Fill(dt);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                dataGridView1.Refresh();

            }
```

Comment: Yes thank you i can accept your question after 8 min

Comment: @user7235054,  You're welcome ! Please accept answer when you get min 8.

Comment: @Toshi, the question was `How can i get the selected column in C#, SQL`

Comment: @Toshi, parameters will not work in OP's case. You cannot use parameter for column or table names

Comment: Coding isn't just getting things somehow done. What if `listBox1` contains `Drop Table Customers` or what ever. The table issue can be solved by a switch

Comment: @Toshi - no you cannot use parameters for column name. Query `SELECT @IdColumnName, @AgeColumnName FROM @PersonTableName` will not work

Comment: @Toshi i dont know what you complaining about it works if you know a better way then post it ;)

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai I dont know why it works so i dont get it

Comment: @Toshi,question was about `How can i get the selected column in C#, SQL`

Comment: @Fabio, you're right : Sql can't have parameters on fieldnames or tablenames, just on values.But in my case i build a string and execute it. See updated answer.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai, feel free to use any approach which works for you. This approach can be safe until this method not exposed in public API of your system(TextBox in the UI for example). If they are - then this approach need strong validation before running query.